# On keyup is not satisfying the condition

Tags: javascript, html, onkeyup

```
<label> Telugu</label>         
    <input type="text" onkeyup="return isNumber(event)" name="telugu"  id="telugu" maxlength="3"/> <br> <br>


JS 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function isNumber(event){
    var k= event.keyCode;
    console.log(k);
    if((k>47 && k<58))   /// THIS IS NOT WORKING
{
        console.log("entered");
        var s1 = document.getElementById("telugu").value;
        var s2= document.getElementById("hindi").value;
        var s3= document.getElementById("english").value;
        var s4= document.getElementById("maths").value;
        var s5= document.getElementById("science").value;
        if(s1<0 || s1>100){
            console.log("tel")
            document.getElementById("telugu").value = 0;      
        }
```

I want to input only numbers in a textbox. the condition is not working. If the value in the textbox is less than 0 or greater than 100. then I am resetting the value to 0. Resetting is working but the characters are also entering.

Comment: If you want only numbers in text box, why can't you just use `<input type=number` ?

Comment: @SaiDatta I want to use textbox so that the design of the form will be good. Using number. down and up arrows are showing up in the number box

Comment: @DivyaGodavarti if that's the only problem you can disable it. Just set [appearance](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/) to none

Comment: @DivyaGodavarti you have error in if condition `if((k>47 && k<58)) ` should be `if(k>47 && k<58) `

Comment: In the code you provided, you're missing two ending brackets. Please add `}}` at the end of your code.

Comment: @CristianTraìna I just wanted to use the javascript function.

Comment: @CodeBug Both are same

Comment: @RickardElimää I just forgot to close here. But actually,  the syntax is fine. The problem is with keyup as it is nor checking the condition. I have tried with  keypress, it is checking, but allowing  101 too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to remove everything that is not a digit. I also change to the [input](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) event which fires whenever the input changes.

If you want to force numbers you could also just set the type to `type="number"`. The benefit for this is that it will automatically show the number keyboard on phones and tablets, though you can show this as well with the `inputmode="numeric"` [attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/inputmode)

```js
// Get the textbox
const telugu = document.getElementById("telugu");

// Add event that fires whenever the input changes
telugu.addEventListener("input", () => {
    // Replace everything that is not a digit with nothing
  const stripped = telugu.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
  
  // If the value is below 0 or above 100 set it to 0, else enter the stripped value
  stripped < 0 || stripped > 100
    ? telugu.value = 0
    : telugu.value = stripped;
});
```

```html
<label for="telugu">Telugu</label>
<input type="text" name="telugu" id="telugu" maxlength="3"/>
```

Without comments:

```js
const telugu = document.getElementById("telugu");

telugu.addEventListener("input", () => {
  const stripped = telugu.value.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");
  
  stripped < 0 || stripped > 100
    ? telugu.value = 0
    : telugu.value = stripped;
});
```

```html
<label for="telugu">Telugu</label>
<input type="text" name="telugu" id="telugu" maxlength="3"/>
```

Simplified:

```js
function validateValue(event) {
  var input = event.target;
  var stripped = input.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""); /* Everthing that is not (^) in the range of 0 through 9 */
  
  if(stripped < 0 || stripped > 100) {
    input.value = 0;
  } else {
    input.value = stripped;
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="telugu">Telugu</label>
<input type="text" oninput="validateValue(event)" name="telugu" id="telugu" maxlength="3"/>
```

Comment: Thank you. It is working but can you please simplify the code in javascript as I am beginner please

Comment: @DivyaGodavarti the last snippet is a simplified version, it looks more like your code. Though it is kinda hard to simplify something like a [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 1):

You should do s1 variable parsed integer with *parseInt()* function.

```js
function isNumber(event){
    var k = event.keyCode;
    console.log(k);
    if(k>47 && k<58){
        console.log("entered");
        var s1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("telugu").value);
        console.log('s1', s1);
        if(s1<0 || s1>100){
            console.log("tel")
            document.getElementById("telugu").value = 0;      
        }
  }else{
    document.getElementById("telugu").value = null;
  }
}
```

```html
<label> Telugu</label>         
<input type="text" onkeyup="return isNumber(event)" name="telugu"  id="telugu" maxlength="3"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to to this.

`input`: Fires when the value of the input has changed.

`change`: Fires when the value of the input has changed **and** the element loses its focus (it is no more selected).

`blur`: Fires when the input losed its focus.

Which event you use, depend on **when** you want to check the input. Use `input` if you want to check it instantly after the change of the value. Otherwise use `blur` or `change`.

Example:

```
let input = document.querySelector('#telegu');
input.addEventListener('input', () => {
    // Your check
});
input.addEventListener('change', () => {
    // Your check
});
input.addEventListener('blur', () => {
    // Your check
});
```